# Is it possible to identify web-socket request on receive?

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I have two queries that are sent one after the other. If I use `send` method, than I get the response in `onmessage` and I need to know which response it was - from the first query or from the second. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a correlation id to each request, and return that id with the response, that way the client would know which response is associated with which request.

Since it is a client concern, the id can be a simple incremental integer, does not need to be a GUID or unique number. The server just have to attach the request id to the response, does not need to do anything with it.